# Unable to map the value to attribute of JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have Json like

```
{"attributea":"value1","attributeb":"value1","data":{"dca":"asd"}}
```

in controller the request attrubutes all are mapped but data attribute is not mapped with object value

contoller is like below

```
insert(@RequestBody Pojo pojo){
```

}

```
Pojo.java class Pojo { String attributea; String attributeb; JSONObject data;}
```

**all values are mapped to attributes** but **data** value is not mapping.please is any thing i am missing ?

**UPDATED: the data is generic it can have any of parameters so i am using its type as JSONObject**

Comment: Are you using `Jackson` or `Gson` for serialization and deserialization? Also I could the input is not a proper json. Please validate.

Comment: please check online how to create POJO class e.g. :http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: *"I have Json like"* No you don't, because that is not valid JSON. You might have *text* like that, but it isn't JSON. See for yourself on https://jsonlint.com/. --- Valid JSON would be `...,"data":{"dca":"asd"}}` or `...,"data":"{\"dca\":\"asd\"}"}`, i.e. the value of `data` is either a JSON object, or a string that happens to be JSON, which would then require another invocation of the JSON parser to process.

Comment: i just changed json, its my type mistake. please check.

Comment: Is it possible you to use a separate pojo class to represent your data instead of using a JSON object.

Comment: @Ranjith data Object is generic. it dont have specific parameters to create a seperate POJO.

Answer (score 0):

Pojo Class.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Pojo implements Serializable{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5065805421422772083L;  
    String attributea; 
    String attributeb; 
    JSONObject data;

    public Pojo(String attributea, String attributeb, JSONObject data) {
        super();
        this.attributea = attributea;
        this.attributeb = attributeb;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Pojo() {
        super();
    }
    //getter setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo [attributea=" + attributea + ", attributeb=" + attributeb + ", data=" + data.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Curl : `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data @data.json http://localhost:<port>/<api>`

data.json contains:

```
{"attributea":"value1", "attributeb":"value1", "data": "{\"dca\": \"asd\"}"}
```

Comment: i have edited my question. it my mistake i kept wrong JSON formate.

Comment: Did you try with Json provided in above answer?

Comment: i have tried but getting this errori have tried but getting this error JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream)

Comment: i have tried but getting this error JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream)

Comment: Can you paste here you POJO code with import statements ?

Comment: in my pojo import statements are import org.json.JSONObject;